# 'Failed to determine a suitable driver class' by running fat jar file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, executable-jar, shadow

I've created a fat-jar file from my spring boot project by using shadow gradle plugin.

Below is part of my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.security.login.LoginApplication',
                'Class-Path': '/libs/authentication.jar'
        )
    }
}
```

After implementing shadow plugin I created a jar file with shadowJar task. But when running the jar file with this command:

```
 java -jar authentication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
```

I encounter with this error:

```
....
17:26:49.343 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
....
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.getDriverClassName(PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
```

This application runs correctly in IntelliJ but the fat-jar file has error.

any help is appreciated.

**Update**

I also tried this method to create a fat-jar:

```
task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.security.login.LoginApplication'
    }
    archiveBaseName = 'PackageDemoJAR'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

But the error still exists!

Comment: Verify that your driver jar is packaged into your fat jar.

Comment: Err, `jar tvf`? But it is already clear that no JDBC driver JAR is packaged with your application. Fix that.